# face api with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure, face-api

I am using azure face api using node js, below is the code. However instead of the image hosted some where i want to use my local image and post it. i tried different options but it is not recognizing the image format or invalid image url

below are the things i have tried

```
1) var stream = fs.createReadStream('local image url');
2) var imageAsBase64 = fs.readFileSync('image.jpg','base64');
```

below is the code

```
'use strict';

const request = require('request');

// Replace <Subscription Key> with your valid subscription key.
const subscriptionKey = '<Subscription Key>';

// You must use the same location in your REST call as you used to get your
// subscription keys. For example, if you got your subscription keys from
// westus, replace "westcentralus" in the URL below with "westus".
const uriBase = 'https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect';

const imageUrl =
    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Dagestani_man_and_woman.jpg';

// Request parameters.
const params = {
    'returnFaceId': 'true',
    'returnFaceLandmarks': 'false',
    'returnFaceAttributes': 'age,gender,headPose,smile,facialHair,glasses,' +
        'emotion,hair,makeup,occlusion,accessories,blur,exposure,noise'
};

const options = {
    uri: uriBase,
    qs: params,
   // body: '{"url": ' + '"' + imageUrl + '"}',
   //body: stream,
   body:imageAsBase64,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' : subscriptionKey
    }
};

request.post(options, (error, response, body) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log('Error: ', error);
    return;
  }
  let jsonResponse = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(body), null, '  ');
  console.log('JSON Response\n');
  console.log(jsonResponse);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I played around with this and got the following code working, you were actually super-close to getting it going. The main thing is to pass the Buffer object to the body field of the POST request, and specifying the correct content-type header.

```
'use strict';

const request = require('request');
const fs = require("fs");

// Replace <Subscription Key> with your valid subscription key.
const subscriptionKey = <Subscription Key> ;

const uriBase = 'https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect';

const imageBuffer = fs.readFileSync('image.jpg');

// Request parameters.
const params = {
    'returnFaceId': 'true',
    'returnFaceLandmarks': 'false',
    'returnFaceAttributes': 'age,gender,headPose,smile,facialHair,glasses,' +
        'emotion,hair,makeup,occlusion,accessories,blur,exposure,noise'
};

const options = {
    uri: uriBase,
    qs: params,
    body: imageBuffer,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' : subscriptionKey
    }
};

request.post(options, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log('Error: ', error);
        return;
    }
    let jsonResponse = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(body), null, '  ');
    console.log('JSON Response\n');
    console.log(jsonResponse);
});
```

Comment: Thank you i will try it this evening!

Comment: Worked like a charmed!

Comment: Is there any benefit to using request over axios for something like this? I'm trying to essentially do the same thing but with axios and I'm not having much luck.

Comment: Axios is probably better if anything, since request is now deprecated. It might just take a bit of playing about with the options to get it to work though.